# Would it make sense for a Validating Notary node to maintain a UTXO set to speed up tx validation?

Tags: corda

It seems maintaining a UTXO set can reduce the computation if we had to run  the ResolveTransactions flow to validate each transaction:

https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-M10.1/key-concepts-data-model.html

When a transaction is presented to a node as part of a flow it may need to be checked. Checking original transaction validity is the responsibility of the ResolveTransactions flow. This flow performs a breadth-first search over the transaction graph, downloading any missing transactions into local storage and validating them. The search bottoms out at transactions without inputs (eg. these are mostly created from issuance transactions). A transaction is not considered valid if any of its transitive dependencies are invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Richard Brown here, CTO at R3.

This is a really good question and one we debated a lot in the early design sessions for Corda.

First, you're 100% right that a notary cluster's job (validating or non-validating) is to maintain a log of spent outputs.  That's how it can make good on its promise never to sign a transaction that attempts to spend a state object that has previously been consumed by a notarised transaction.

As for caching *unspent* outputs, it wouldn't reduce actually computation - just move the time at which you paid the cost, right?  ie when the output is created rather than when it is consumed.  But it would also result in a reduction in privacy: the existence of an unspent output would be revealed to the notary way before it is actually consumed.

And note: in the general case, the same notary cluster will be used for most transactions in a series... so there won't actually be anything to resolve.  The notary cluster will already know the dependencies because it notarised the previous transaction too.

When a notary *does* change then yes.. there could conceivably be a lot of transaction resolution to do.  But, again, pre-notifying the notary of the new UTXO just changes *when* that work has to be done.  I agree it could improve latency in some edge cases so it's not something I rule out.  But, right now, the system works as you describe:  notary clusters only learn of the existence of an output when it is spent.  ie we prioritise privacy to the greatest extent possible.

Comment: Thank you Richard for taking my question, explaining the design choice and confirming that the current Notary makes decisions based on the Spent TXO set. I think I see your point to maximize the privacy and also in the same notary scenario, if it were to maintain a separate UTXO set, it won't give a performance boost assuming that the entire Spent TXO set can be cached as good as the entire UTXO set. However, due to different growth rates in size, in the long run (say for 10 years, 1000 tps) we may expect caching the entire UTXO set be more manageable than caching the entire Spent TXO set.

Comment: Very good point re the long-term tradeoff! But I think you also have to think about another scenario: Imagine I create a transaction that creates a new output.  In your model, it would be added to the UTXO set.  Now... some time later, you try to spend the output.  Great.. that works and the state is removed from the UTXO set.  But what stops you (or me) resubmitting the _original_ transaction back to the notary and making the output _reappear_ as a UTXO?  I could only stop that by logging the UTXO as an STXO.. and we're back to the same storage requirement, no?

Comment: I see the storage requirement of STXO is not optional by design. In case when STXO grows too big, perhaps additional UTXO can be employed and treated as the first level cache (on fastest/pricy storage) and when missed, it then resorts to STXO as the second level (on cheaper/volume storage).

Answer (score 2):

To answer myself, maintaining a UTXO set would speed things up. Yet, it has to maintain a Spent TXO set as well to achieve the best performance.